# multiple https sites on the same with one IP:Port IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, https, iis-7.5

I have a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 box running IIS 7.5 with two HTTPS sites. The server also runs Exchange 2010 so the Default Web Site uses HTTPS and i have another site which should also use HTTPS. I have tried the following:
https://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html
and still receive the error "This Web site cannot be started. Another Web site may be using the same port" when attempting to start the second of the two sites at a time.

I have also had a look in the applicationHost.config file and saw the following the Default web site uses the default HTTPS binding (*:443) and the second uses www.domain.com:443.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this server is running Exchange Server 2010 then you probably shouldn't be also using it as a general purpose web server. Host your websites on a different server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if running exchange on the box will complicate matters, but change the default website's binding from `*:443` to `mydefaultdomain.name:443`

Comment: If this answer doesn't work, why is the check-mark there?

Answer (score 0):

What is the second site for? 
An Exchange server should be doing just that, no hosting anything else.

If it is an internal resource, can it not be hosted elsewhere? 
Otherwise a second IP address and being very careful with the bindings can work, but it isn't recommended.

Simon.